# How to make animation of changing background vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have few components, and when i select one of them style of div element  changes(in this case background). I need to make to it some fade animation like this:

```
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
```

element and styles:

```
  <div class="wrapWindow__atm " :class="{section__atm: !(isComponent == 'mainatm')}">
  </div>
```

```
.wrapWindow__atm {


  background: black;
  background-size: contain;
}

.section__atm {
  background: red;
  transition: opacity 3s ease; // doesn't work
}
```

can't find any soultion to do it, any ideas?

Comment: It not work because there is no `opacity` attribute to make the transition. Why not use `background` instead? It work well imo, transition from one color to another.

Comment: As you provided css transition references, animations mostly tend to be css related, using vue you could use intervals to make changes on class or background image url but not perform animations.